# HW-Acceleration on Ubuntu Server

Tags: drivers, server, hardware-acceleration

I've installed Plex server on my server (well, basically it's a Dell 7720 that I turned into a server) and I'm trying to get hardware-acceleration to work.

But it seems that in order to install the required drivers for this, the X-Server gets installed too (which isn't really useful at all for a server).

Is it possible to still enable HW-Acceleration without a GUI? Or is this always required for this to function?

My specs:

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- CPU: Intel i7-3630QM
- GPU: NVidia Geforce GT650M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems like there's no way to do this without an X-server.
However, it seems you're able to install the X-Server without running any kind of desktop environment, so the performance impact is absolutely minimal and definitely worth the tradeoff vs hardware acceleration.